# WPF - grid columns resize

Tags: wpf

Can I do something to resize columns *width* by moving some line between them? I need it to make one of images *bigger* for a while.

Grid Code:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Name="IMG1"/>
        <Image Name="IMG2"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [GridSplitter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter.aspx) between your two images